# Moving data from table to multiple tables depending on condition

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to move data from one table to other two tables depending on if certain condition is met.

This is what i was trying with:

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM rac_temp_import
    WHERE depo IN ('0281752') AND tura IN ('026','094','097')
    RETURNING *, (CASE WHEN parcelno IN(
        SELECT parcelno FROM rac_import
        UNION
        SELECT parcelno FROM rac_dupli
    ) THEN true ELSE false END) AS dupli
)
INSERT INTO rac_dupli
SELECT FROM moved_rows WHERE dupli = true
INSERT INTO rac_import
SELECT FROM moved_row WHERE dupli = false
```

But as far as i understand only one `INSERT` statement can exist after `WITH` and i tried using `CASE` after but that didn't work either.

Comment: Use a (temp) table instead of the CTE. Or transform the CTE into a (temp) view.

Comment: You dont have to first set a flag and later use it; you can move the exists() conditions to the insert into {rac_dupl,rac_import} parts, where they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the first `insert` a CTE:

```
with moved_rows as (
    delete from rac_temp_import rti
    where depo in ('0281752') and tura in ('026','094','097')
    returning *,
        exists (
            select parcelno
            from rac_import
            where parcelno = rti.parcelno
        ) or
        exists (
            select parcelno
            from rac_dupli
            where parcelno = rti.parcelno
        ) as dupli
), i as (
    insert into rac_dupli
    select
    from moved_rows
    where dupli = true
)
insert into rac_import
select
from moved_rows
where dupli = false
```

`exists` might be faster than the `case in`